# CloudFormation TaskDefinition with two different entry points based on condition

Tags: aws-cloudformation, ecs-taskdefinition

I have to add taskdefintion entry based on condition. Below is the template  i created.

```
Conditions
IsProdEnv:  !Equals [ !Ref envtype, "prod" ] 

TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
        ContainerDefinitions:
            EntryPoint:
              - !If [IsProdEnv, !Split [",", ["python3", "hello.py"]], "./script.sh"]
```

I'm getting

> Template error: every Fn::Split object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a string to be split or a function that returns a string to be split.

Answer (score 1):

You have two strings instead of one: `"python3"` and `"hello.py"`. You need to have one string, e.g. `"python3, hello.py"`. How this string looks, depends on your use-case.

Comment: I tried that way too. Got below error.
Resource handler returned message: "Model validation failed (#/ContainerDefinitions/0/VolumesFrom/0/ReadOnly:expected type: Boolean, found: String #/ContainerDefinitions/0/EntryPoint/3:expected type: String, found: JSONArray #/ContainerDefinitions/0/Essential: expected type: Boolean, found: String #/ContainerDefinitions/0/MountPoints/0/ReadOnly: expected type: Boolean, found: String #/ContainerDefinitions/1/Essential: expected type: Boolean, found: String #/ContainerDefinitions/1/MountPoints/0/ReadOnly: expected type: Boolean, found: String)"